# Как с применением семафоров POSIX долждаться 0-го значения семафора?

Tags: c, linux, posix

Ситуация : есть некий ресурс и взаимоисключающие операции A и B.
т.е. можем иметь подобный расклад

- изначально счётчик проводящих A процессов имеет нулевое значение
- после N потоков начинают операцию A и проводят её в течение какого-то времени
- N+1 поток для проведения операции B должен дождаться завершения операций A вышеупомянутыми потоками.

на момент инициализации N неизвестен.

Т.е. хотелось бы подобного

- `semvalue = 0` (в инициализации)
- `for i=1,N,1 {semvalue++;A();semvalue--}`
- `while(semvalue!=0); B()`

Как лучше организовать подобное?

Answer (score 2):

Если задача именно такая, как сформулирована в тексте вопроса (не в заголовке), а именно -- *параллельно выполнить операцию A в N потоках, а после их завершения выполнить B*, то никакие семафоры/мьютексы для ее синхронизации не нужны.

Псевдокод:

```
pthread_t tid[N];
void *arg[N]; // аргументы для каждой A
void *res[N]; // результаты каждой A

for (int i = 0; i <N; i++)
  tid[i] = pthread_create(tid + i, 0, A, arg[i]);
for (int i = 0; i <N; i++)
  pthread_join(tid[i], res[i]);
B();
```

Достаточно просто дождаться завершения N потоков, а потом выполнить B().

**Update**

Я понял, что вас интересует более общий случай. Синхронизировать количество потоков каждого вида (A и B) можно используя pthread_mutex вместе с pthread_cond.

Безусловно, то же можно сделать, используя вместо pthread.h semaphore.h (см. man  semaphore.h), но я сейчас лучше помню работу с мьютексами.

Вот, набросал игрушку, котрая иллюстрирует работающий подход

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ cat cp.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 3

volatile int Acnt = 0, Bcnt = 0, Alim = N;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cond;

void *thA (void *a) {
  int i = (long)a;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  printf("A:%d start (%d A %d B Alim: %d)\n", i, Acnt, Bcnt, Alim);
  while (Acnt + 1 > Alim)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
  Acnt++;
  printf("A:%d run (%d A %d B Alim: %d)\n", i, Acnt, Bcnt, Alim);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

  // work
  usleep(rand() % 1000000);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  Acnt--;
  printf("A:%d stop (%d A %d B Alim: %d)\n", i, Acnt, Bcnt, Alim);
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void *thB (void *a) {
  int i = (long)a;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  printf("B:%d start (%d A %d B Alim: %d)\n", i, Acnt, Bcnt, Alim);
  while (Acnt > 0 || Bcnt > 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
  Bcnt++;
  printf("B:%d run (%d A %d B Alim: %d)\n", i, Acnt, Bcnt, Alim);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

  // work
  usleep(rand() % 1000000);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  Bcnt--;
  printf("B:%d stop (%d A %d B Alim: %d)\n", i, Acnt, Bcnt, Alim);
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}



pthread_t runA (int i) {
  pthread_t r; 
  return pthread_create(&r, 0, thA, (void *)(long)i), r;
}
pthread_t runB (int i) {
  pthread_t r; 
  return pthread_create(&r, 0, thB, (void *)(long)i), r;
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  pthread_mutex_init(&lock, 0);
  pthread_cond_init(&cond, 0);

  pthread_t all[10000];
  int c, i, n = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (isdigit(c))
      Alim = c - '0' + 1;
    else
      all[n++] =  (c == 'a')? runA(n) : runB(n);
    usleep(100);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("thread %d join %d\n", i + 1, pthread_join(all[i], 0));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gcc  cp.c -pthread
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 
baa
B:1 start (0 A 0 B Alim: 3)
B:1 run (0 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:3 start (0 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:3 run (1 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:2 start (1 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:2 run (2 A 1 B Alim: 3)
B:4 start (2 A 1 B Alim: 3)
B:1 stop (2 A 0 B Alim: 3)
A:2 stop (1 A 0 B Alim: 3)
A:3 stop (0 A 0 B Alim: 3)
B:4 run (0 A 1 B Alim: 3)
B:4 stop (0 A 0 B Alim: 3)
baaab
B:5 start (0 A 0 B Alim: 3)
B:5 run (0 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:6 start (0 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:6 run (1 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:7 start (1 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:7 run (2 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:8 start (2 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:8 run (3 A 1 B Alim: 3)
B:9 start (3 A 1 B Alim: 3)
B:10 start (3 A 1 B Alim: 3)
A:6 stop (2 A 1 B Alim: 3)
B:5 stop (2 A 0 B Alim: 3)
A:8 stop (1 A 0 B Alim: 3)
A:7 stop (0 A 0 B Alim: 3)
B:9 run (0 A 1 B Alim: 3)
B:9 stop (0 A 0 B Alim: 3)
B:10 run (0 A 1 B Alim: 3)
B:10 stop (0 A 0 B Alim: 3)
thread 1 join 0
thread 2 join 0
thread 3 join 0
thread 4 join 0
thread 5 join 0
thread 6 join 0
thread 7 join 0
thread 8 join 0
thread 9 join 0
thread 10 join 0
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Как работают pthread_cond_wait и pthread_cond_broadcast (именно на них построена синхронизация в этой программке) почитайте в `man`.

Если вопросы останутся -- задавайте.

Comment: Дело в том, что эти потоки продолжают выполнять дальше другие задачи.

Comment: @user3476487, добавил **Update** с примером кода для синхронизации групп потоков.

Answer (score 0):

Покрайней мере мы должны знать сколько запустили потоков с задачей А, значит
можно использовать атомарную переменную вместо семафора:

```
int RUNNING_THREADS = N;
for(int i = 0; i < RUNNING_THREADS; i++)
    run_thread(&RUNNING_THREADS);
```

В контексте каждого потока:

```
A();
if(__sync_fetch_and_sub(RUNNING_THREADS, 1) == 0) {
    B(); // Потоков выполняющих задачу А нет, запускаем выполнение задачи B
}
```

По поводу использования атомарных переменных в GCC.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Из описания не понятно, почему N определить не удается на этапе инициализации. Если изначально запускаются N потоков с задачей А.

Comment: Нет возможности узнать N - потому что мьютексы расшарены между процессами, а вот процессы далее инициализирующего уже позже запускаются юзером (странное устройство, но требуется такое, да)

Comment: Хорошо, тогда я думаю можно использовать [общую память](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) и расшаренный мьютекс для синхронизации доступа к ней. А в памяти разместить счетчик потоков, которые запускает юзер.